# Filling NaN in a DataFrame Column with Key from a Dictionary by looking up values from a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
> Country                     Code
> 'Bolivia'                   NaN
> 'Bolivia, The Republic of'  NaN
```

And I also have a dictionary

```
> CountryCode = {'BOL':['Bolivia','Bolivia, The Republic of']}
```

How do I go on about fillna in the dataframe with the respective Key if one of the values is in the dictionary?

The desired output is

```
> Country                     Code
> 'Bolivia'                   'BOL'
> 'Bolivia, The Republic of'  'BOL'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create reverse dictionary of `CountryCode` and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) it with `Country` column:

```
new_countrycode = {v:key for key,value in CountryCode.items() for v in value}
df['Code'] = df['Country'].map(new_countrycode)

print(df)
                    Country Code
0                   Bolivia  BOL
1  Bolivia, The Republic of  BOL

print(new_countrycode)
{'Bolivia': 'BOL', 'Bolivia, The Republic of': 'BOL'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df["Code"] = df.Country.apply(lambda x: ''.join(i for i, j in CountryCode.items() if x in j))
```

Output:

```
                    Country Code
0                   Bolivia  BOL
1  Bolivia, The Republic of  BOL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Bolivia','Bolivia, The Republic of'],'code':[None,None]})
```

Create Dataframe from dictionary of key-value code

```
df_keyval=pd.DataFrame({'CountryCode':{'BOL':['Bolivia','Bolivia, The Republic of']}}).reset_index()
```

Match the Country and get the corresponding Key:

```
for idx,rows in df.iterrows():
    if rows['Country'] in df_keyval.CountryCode[0]:
        df['code']=df_keyval.index[0]
```

**Output:**

```
    Country                    code
0   Bolivia                     BOL
1   Bolivia, The Republic of    BOL
```